# When exactly is drawInMTKView called?

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation, metal, metalkit

MetalKit calls `drawInMTKView` when it wants a your delegate to draw a new frame, but I wonder if it waits for the last drawable to have been presented before it asks your delegate to draw on a new one?

From what I understand reading [this article](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/resource_synchronization/synchronizing_cpu_and_gpu_work), CoreAnimation can provide up to three "in flight" drawables, but I can't find whether MetalKit tries to draw to them as soon as possible or if it waits for *something else* to happen.

What would this *something else be*? What confuses me a little is the idea of drawing to up to two frames in advance, since it means the CPU must already know what it wants to render two frames in the future, and I feel like it isn't always the case. For instance if your application depends on user input, you can't know upfront the actions the user will have done between now and when the two frames you are drawing to will be presented, so they may be presented with out of date content. Is this assumption right? In this case, it could make some sense to only call the delegate method at a maximum rate determined by the intended frame rate.

The problem with synchronizing with the frame rate is that this means the CPU may sometimes be inactive when it could have done some useful work.

I also have the intuition this may not be happening this way since in the article aforementioned, it seems like `drawInMTKView` is called as often as a drawable is available, since they seem to rely on it being called to make work that uses resources in a way that avoids CPU stalling, but since there are many points that are unclear to me I am not sure of what is happening exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MTKView` documentation mentions in `paused` page that

> If the value is `NO`, the view periodically redraws the contents, at a frame rate set by the value of `preferredFramesPerSecond`.

Based on samples there are for `MTKView`, it probably uses a combination of an internal timer and `CVDisplayLink` callbacks. Which means it will basically choose the "right" interval to call your drawing function at the right times, usually after other drawable is shown "on-glass", so at V-Sync interval points, so that your frame has the most CPU time to get drawn.

You can make your own view and use `CVDisplayLink` or `CADisplayLink` to manage the rate at which your draws are called. There are also other ways such as relying on back pressure of the drawable queue (basically just calling `nextDrawable` in a loop, because it will block the thread until the drawable is available) or using `presentAfterMinimumDuration`. Some of these are discussed in this [WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10147/).

I think Core Animation triple buffers everything that gets composed by Window Server, so basically it waits for you to finish drawing your frame, then it draws it with the other frames and then presents it to "glass".

As to a your question about the delay: you are right, the CPU is two or even three "frames" ahead of the GPU. I am not too familiar with this, and I haven't tried it, but I think it's possible to actually "skip" the frames you drew ahead of time if you delay the presentation of your drawables up until the last moment, possibly until scheduled handler on one of your command buffers.

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed answer! I will take some time to explore all of this into more detail and familiarize myself a bit more with CADisplayLink and V-Sync.